# Native mobile browser select element options count

Tags: android, html, iphone, forms, drop-down-menu

How many options from a standard select element fit on the portrait-oriented screen of a given popular device?

For example, my Pixel 2 fits 9 options (9.5, but I'm looking for wholly visible options)

The purpose of this question is that I have a drop down selector where I don't really need to display all of the options, but more is better. I also think that not having the user scroll is advantageous. I'm trying to find a happy number where I can display the most options without causing those options to overflow the device height.

Since I only have the one mobile device, and nowhere is this data readily available, I'm turning to you.

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone X legibly shows 7. My iPad shows a bunch. Easily 15 depending on where the dropdown is in the screen, since it's more of a desktop style.